# Calling default constructor in return statement

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have a trivial class:

```
class Temp {
    private:
        int vals;
    public:
        Temp():vals(0);
        Temp(int x):vals(x);
        Temp& someFunc(const Temp& t);
};
```

And say `someFunc` has a condition where it would call the following:

```
return Temp null_t; // not allowed for some reason
```

And yet, this works (as it is expected to):

```
Temp null_t;
return null_t;
```

Why can I not call the default constructor in the same line as the `return`?

**Edit (someFunc implementation):**

```
Temp& Temp::someFunc(const Temp& rhs) {
    if (this->vals == rhs.vals) {
        // return a reference to an empty Temp object
        *this = Temp(); // dereference, copy-assignment
        return *this;
    this->vals = rhs.vals
    return *this
}
```

Comment: Because syntax.

Comment: A return statement cannot contain a declaration.

Comment: @NeilButterworth This is the first time I am trying to do this with a user defined class, can you expand on what the syntax is?

Comment: Try the same with an `int`. Does `return int 42;` work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your function were to return by value (i.e. `Temp someFunc(const Temp&)`, then you can do that just using an actual temporary, not a named variable (which isn't temporary):

```
return Temp();
```

If the return type is not a class type with an explicit default constructor, you can also say:

```
return {};
```

However, since you want to return an lvalue ("return a reference"), it doesn't make sense to either return a (reference to) a temporary, nor does it make sense to return (a reference to)your `null_t`, since neither will live long enough and the return value would immediately be invalid. Your function call can only make reference to something that still exists when the function returns.

Comment: Let's not forget `someFunc` returns a reference!

Comment: @O'Neil: Errr... yes, none of this makes sense then. Whoops.

Comment: @O'Neil: Updated, somehow.

Comment: I just wanted to create a new ("nulled") instance and return it by reference; so what is wrong if I choose to return a named variable that has its default ctor defined with an initialization list?

Comment: @pstatix: The reference is immediately dangling, so the result of the function call could never be used. It's totally unclear what you even *mean* to do. In your mind, what would the function result refer *to*?

Comment: @KerrekSB Inside `someFunc` is an `if` condition; should that condition be met, I want to return a reference to a new, empty object. Suppose it is called as `t3 = t1.someFunc(t2)`, if the condition is met, the `t3` will be a reference to a newly created object, otherwise it will be a reference to the altered `t1` (via `return *this`). So by creating a new object inside `someFunc` and returning it, that object will be destroyed when `someFunc` completes since it was locally declared, thus making it dangling?

Comment: @pstatix: Correct. Generally, if you want to talk about existing objects (which is what you do when you use references), it is upon *you* to arrange the actual existence of such objects, and manage their lifetimes. There isn't a simple answer, because this isn't a simple question about how to do a particular thing, but rather a symptom of some big design problem. For example, what should happen when someone modifies that "new object" you're talking about? Where does it live? Does every call create a new such object?

Comment: @pstatix: A complete guess in the dark, but I imagine that it's much more likely that your *caller* will want to know the result of that condition you mention, and if the condition is false, the caller probably won't want to act on the (non-existing) object at all, but do something different instead. In that case, it would be more appropriate to return a pointer to the existing object if the condition is true, and a null pointer otherwise.

Comment: @KerrekSB I've updated my question with a pseudo-implementation. I think it is wise to either: make the condition do `*this = Temp(); return *this` or somehow return a `nullptr`; the latter doesn't seem to be working (or I am not sure how to implement as `return nullptr` doesnt align with the return type.

Comment: @KerrekSB Is it possible to return a reference to a `nullptr`?

Comment: @KerrekSB Nevermind, my implementation now works and is (I believe) syntactically correct using `*this = Temp(); return *this;`.

Answer (score 6):

> Why can I not call the default constructor in the same line as the return?

Well, you actually can:

```
return Temp{};
```